# Sas add all variable values to macros. Cycle

Tags: variables, sas, macros, cycle

I have already some table like this [image]

with 177 values. I need to call some macros with all this values step by step
for example: %somemacros(CountRenewLong_00_01); then %somemacros(CountRenewLong_00_02); and till 177;

How I can do it automatically using my table Table1?

Thank you for helping!

Comment: What is that a photograph of?  Is it the contents of a dataset with a variable named 'Variable Name'n (or with a label of 'Variable Name') ?  Or is the output of PROC CONTENTS?  What is that second column? Why does it start with 3 instead of 1?  Does that mean you only want some of the names (or some of values)?

Answer (score 0):

`CALL EXECUTE()` is what you're looking for there.
Assuming your data set is called HAVE, this should work for you.

I would STRONGLY recommend commenting out the `call execute` line, verifying that the `str` variable contains the macro code you expect and then running it once you're sure it is correct.

```
data callMacros;
  set have;

  str = catt('%somemacros(', variableName, ');');

  call execute(str);
run;
```

https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=mcrolref&docsetTarget=n1q1527d51eivsn1ob5hnz0yd1hx.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en